# How do I access files hosted on web via python?

Tags: python, localhost, remote-access

I am working on a system (python program) that runs on local machine but it needs to fetch data hosted somewhere on web (images in my case).
What it does is:

1. Send a SQL query to webhost (`localhost` currently)
2. The response sends back the names of images (it is stored in an array called `fetchedImages` lets assume).

Now once I have all the names of required images all I want to do is access the file directly from `localhost` and copy it to local machine. But this is what my problem is:

I am trying to access it as:

```
source = "localhost/my-site/images"
localDir = "../images"

for image in fetchedImages:
    copy(source+image,localDir)
```

but the problem is that, the localhost is created using XAMPP and I cannot access `localhost` since python doesn't accept it as path. How can I access localhost if it isn't created via `SimpleHTTPServer` but XAMPP?

Comment: **localhost** is just another way of saying the IP address that you are trying to access, but if you just want to copy it on your local drive why don't you use the normal path where the XAMP has all the information? For example `source = "C:\Xampp\htdocs\my-site\images\"` for Windows.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing currently, but I plan to host the website on remote host later (```www.my-site.com```). That is why I don't want to go with ```source = "C:\Xampp\htdocs\my-site\images\"```. If I design it this way right now, it will be felxible to adopt path changes since it will not be working on static path anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved using `requests` as:

```
import requests as req
from StringIO import StringIO
from PIL import Image

source = "http://localhost/my-site/images/"
localDir = "../images"

for image in fetchedImages:
    remoteImage = req.get(source+image)
    imgToCopy = Image.open(StringIO(remoteImage.content))
    imgToCopy.save(localDir+image)
```

the `requests` will access the web resource thus making system easy to work with dynamic paths (`localhost/my-site` or `www.my-site.com`) and then copy those resources to local machine for processing.